# Скульптор, делающий только статуэтки - как его назвать?

Tags: выбор-слова, одним-словом

Большая часть собственно в заголовке. Скульптор — очень общее слово, и скорей ассоциируется со статуями (которые большие, в полный рост, или если даже бюсты которые вроде небольшие, но все равно в натуральную величину). А есть ли слово для людей которые лепят (или ваяют) именно небольшие статуэтки (1:10 и меньше)?

Answer (score 6):

Наиболее близкое к искомому идеалу слово - `резчик`.
У этого слова есть смежное значение - резчик по дереву, он не обязательно вырезает статуэтки, а, например, создаёт деревянные узоры. Тем не менее, человека, который занимается  только созданием статуэток назовут резчиком.

[Пример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) использования:

> В Японии со средних веков до периода Мэйдзи сложились школы резчиков
>   прикладных фигурок-нэцкэ и комнатных статуэток окимоно.

Но "резчик" - это всё-так больше про дерево, про кость, может быть, про камень. Создателя стеклянных статуэток можно назвать стеклодувом, специализирующемся на [миниатюрной пластике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0), глиняных - мастером / кузнецом художественной керамики (керамистом), металлических - мастером художественной ковки.

Какого-то универсального слова мне не известно (что, разумеется, не значит, что его в принципе не существует - но это маловероятно ;)

В общем-то, тут дело ещё и в том, что люди, скажем, делающие керамические статуэтки редко делали только их - например, они делали ещё посуду. Есть очень "канцеляритское", официозное понятие [художник декоративно-прикладного искусства](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), из которого получается чуть менее официозное - `художник-прикладник` (или даже просто - `прикладник`). Этот термин тоже уместен, если мы говорим о скульпторе, специализирующемся исключительно на малой форме.

Кстати, комбинированный термин `скульптор-прикладник` (как противопоставление `скульптору-монументалисту`) тоже существует.

Comment: интересно, кстати, как называли мастеров до того, как их стали называть мастерами.

Comment: Ну слово "мастер" происходит от цеховой иерархии и обозначает, в конечном счете, уровень профессиональных умений по стандартам оной. В отсутствии же её никакого общего термина, мне думается, просто не было. То есть игрец/кузнец/резчик/ваятель, хороший/плохой и т.п. Конечно, если говорящий того хотел, он вполне мог использовать какое-нибудь слово наподобие "искусник", но оно явно бы имело смысл только в определенном контексте.

Comment: @Matt  ну вот в украинском для прикладников есть слово "митець" -  в устаревшей форме "мистець" - ииии - тут вот на этом месте у меня закрались подозрение, не от мастер ли и это тоже )

Comment: Ну слово "мастер" известно по крайней мере с 13 века. Плюс "мастак", согласно Фасмеру, произошёл уже именно от "мастера", а никак иначе. Логично предположить, что и история слова "мистець" точно такая же.

Comment: Слов связанных с материалом с которым мастер работает немало, да. Интересно именно разделение по размерам. Но, возможно, такого слова и не существует. @Matt, искусник, как мне кажется, это степень мастерства, которую можно применить к любому художнику прикладного искусства.